# Spring cloud Api Gateway: does the traffic pass through it or it just redirects the client

Tags: spring-cloud-gateway

I am new to Spring.
When writing Microservices there is an Api-Gateway placed before the internal network of microservices to be accessed from public network.

I understand that using spring cloud gateway we can create an api-gateway service and specify the routes in the configuration of the api-gateway.

My question is whether all the traffic passes through the process of api-gateway until the actual data is returned to the end client ? Or whether only the initial call is directed towards the api-gateway and the rest of data exchange happens without api-gateway in the middle ?